# How to create a Recycler Grid View with horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am loading icons in a recycler view using GridLayout. I am able to scroll the items vertically in a grid. But I want to scroll the items horizontally in the same GridLayout. I am looking for view pager for recycler view or horizontol scroll bars for recycler grid view. Can someone suggest me how this can be achieved? Also if I could use better design than this to achieve the same. That is to load the icons with optimal memory usage.

Comment: Thank you. I played with the sample app. The items in each grid are scrolling vertically. I want to enable horizontal scrolling similar to scrolling pages for the items in the grid.

Answer (score 6):

The GridLayoutManager has the following Constructor: `GridLayoutManager (Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)`

As you can see you can pass an int for the orientation. 
One possible option is `HORIZONTAL`. This is what you want.

More here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html

Comment: Thank you. This enabled horizontal scrolling of elements in gridview. But the scrolling is too fast. I want a scrolling similar to scrolling pages.

Answer (score 0):

[TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/) can do it. [Sample project](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/tree/master/sample).